# singleTask launchMode in android not working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-navigation

So, I have 4 activities Activity `Activity1`, `Activity2`, `Activity3` and `Activity4`. I start from `Activity1` then on some event I start `Activity2` then on some event on `Activity2` I start `Activity3` as a new task as

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here `Activity2` launchMode is decalared as singleTask.

Then I navigate from `Activity3` to `Activity4`

When I start `Activity2` from `Activity4` I believe it should have backstack like

Task A

|Activity2|

|Activity1|

Task B

|Activity4|

|Activity3|

as shown in image below[image]

but instead new instance of `Activity2` is added to the current task as

Task B

|Activity2|

|Activity4|

|Activity3|

Task A

|Activity2|

|Activity1|

can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: have you set the `launchMode="singleTask"` flag to Activity3 tag in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Yes I set the `launchMode="singleTask"` flag.

Comment: hey, don't use this flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` in setFlags method. Simply use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`(if required).

Comment: Simply adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` won't create a new task for the new activity.

Comment: in my code i used only FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to perform same as what u actually want.

Comment: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` wont push current task to background

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android will not create a new task unless the `taskAffinity` of the `Activity` you are trying to launch is different from the `taskAffinity` of the current task. `taskAffinity` takes precendence over anything else.

If you really want to start a separate task, you'll need to adjust the `taskAffinity` of the `Activity3` like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity3"
          android:taskAffinity=""/>
```

Also, even though `Activity4` is declared with `launchMode="singleTask"`, Android will not create a new task for it unless if has a different `taskAffinity` from the other activities.

Please be aware that creating multiple tasks for the same application has a lot of side-effects. You should provide a uniqyue icon and a unique label for the root `Activity` in each task, otherwise the user will be confused when he wants to return to your app (he won't be able to determine which of the various tasks is the correct one). Also, `taskReparenting` can occur which will unexpectedly move activities from one task to another. This is all very complex stuff and most developers don't completely understand it and therefore get it wrong.

Also, the use of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` is certainly wrong. The only type of application that needs to use this is a launcher. If you launch multiple tasks with the same `Activity` in it, you will never be able to return to a specific one programatically, and will totally confuse your user. This is definitely not what you want.

In most cases you don't need multiple tasks, it usually causes more problems than it solves. Please explain why you think you need multiple tasks.