# Not Working corss-application activities with taskAffinity in Android 11

Tags: android, android-activity, android-11, cross-application, taskaffinity

I have two application, App A and App B, now I want to start an activity in App B from App A, the launchmode of this Activity is “singleTask”.

The order:
Activity X (App A) ———> Activity Y (App B) ———> Activity Z (App B, launchMode=“singleTask”)

As default AndroidManifest config, there will be two App shown in the Task Manager, I hope users can only see App A label in Task Manager, so when they switch between tasks they don’t click App B. Before Android 11(Android R), I use the attribute taskAffinity as below to solve this problem.

Both Activity X and Activity Z,  add this in AndroidManifet.xml

`android:taskAffinity="com.abc.xxx”`

So these activity can both house in one activity task. **In Android 10, it works.**

**However, it doen’t work in Android11 anymore.** And, I didn’t find any new features relevant to this scene.

How can I make ApplicationA’s activity task house the activity of ApplicationB which launchmode is singleTask? Let users see only one task(ApplicationA) in task manager.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. And you shouldn't. The reason it was working before is that `taskAffinity` was trumping (overriding) the `launchMode`. Obviously they have changed/fixed that in Android 11.

If an `Activity` is declared as `singleTask` then this tells Android that the `Activity` wants to be the root `Activity` in its own task. When you launch this `Activity`, it should be launched in a new task, not into the same task as the `Activity` doing the launching.

In earlier versions of Android, the `Activity` would be launched into the same task if the `Activity` had the same`taskAffinity` as the root `Activity` of the launching task. This was never clearly documented, and so it wasn't clear if this was a "bug" or a "feature". It looks like they have finally changed/fixed this in Android 11.

See my answers to these related questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991392/769265
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36127362/769265
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18622131/769265

Comment: So how can I let users see only one task when they switch tasks?

Comment: Remove the special launch mode `singleTask` from the `<activity>` declaration. Generally this launch mode is not required.

Comment: This maybe right.
But through https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#Affinities this document point out and explain that it can be used across applications.
And I test Android 10 is working but Android 11 is not.
So this may be a bug and fixed in Android 11